# A word that means "Goodbye to a year"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

My friends called me asking if there's a word to say "goodbye to a year", like lets say this:

"Today, we're saying to 2018"

Is there a single word, a verb that doesn't require the use of

"Saying x to y"

Like the actual verb of leaving the year, not just "saying farewell"

I think I remember such that such word exists in french but my memory is rusty therefore I can't quite remember the actual word, I want it in English though

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy9_lfjQopU

Comment: @HotLicks That's awesome little video :) but I didn't find what I'm looking for, I guess the word doesn't exist in English so I just told my friends to either say goodbye or farewell :)

Comment: Should your 2nd sentence be "Today, we're saying *farewell* to 2018"?

Comment: @MartinF Yes that's what I meant

Comment: I suggest using the **[edit]** button.

Comment: @MartinF Ah that's not what I meant, I meant that is there a way to say goodbye to a year without using "saying" or "say" and the suggested is answer is "today we are farewelling a year" . In short I didn't want to use a sentence which looks like "today we are saying x to y"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *farewell* as a verb:

> Northbridge is the place to be when farewelling 2018.

https://www.visitperth.com.au/events/new-years-eve-in-the-city

> Many of the region’s farming families will be looking forward to farewelling 2018 after a tough year battling the drought and unpredictable weather.

https://www.theherald.com.au/story/5826399/hold-on-for-deer-life-santas-on-his-way/?cs=7597

> New Year’s Eve preparations are under way across the country as thousands of people scope the best vantage points to watch the fireworks farewelling 2018 on Monday night.

https://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/nation/eyes-of-the-world-will-be-on-sydney/news-story/2781f6ea538b15d26c05b9a6e3f33083?nk=f4c452d1b73db4aa236c3a71c9e73545-1546192303

> Christmas trading hours are up! Let's farewell 2018 the right way. Get away from the crowds and hideout with us

https://www.picomico.com/p/1930383241183644116_4022311982

Given the distribution of examples, it seems like this is only used in Australia.   However it would be understood anywhere as long as you don’t use the imperative.

Comment: Lots more where that came from; for example, [*“As they drove off I..was unpleasantly **adieued** by your sister, who through the window gave me a haughty look.**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/290348)

Comment: You may be able to use farewell as a verb, but if I did people would laugh in my face.